# Is there a vs code extension that splits long LaTeX lines to shorter ones?

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code

Is there any visual studio code extension that autoformats the LaTeX code such that it splits too long lines to shorter ones? I would like to write articles but I would like to avoid pressing enter if in the paragraph I write and I hate horizontal scrolling. I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: [Word wrap](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.tadris.fitness/) is implemented - hotkey <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (ALT+Z - how is my html not working here?)